# open new window / tab after form submit using an drupal javascript invoke

Tags: php, javascript, function, drupal-7

yes this question is asked some times. but I can't find an answer for my problem.
I've posted my question here because it is more php / javascript related then drupal I guess.

So basically I have a form that is validated and on the submit part I have a ( drupal hook ) function in php where I can add / modify code. 
This function catches the form fields and stores them in the database.
This means that the fields are filled correctly so I want to implement something here that opens a new tab or window for the user without closing the current one.

So I know you can't call javascript from php to use something like `window.open()` but is there anyway I can make it so that this `window.open()` is called?

I'm also open for a bit different approach if you have any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an anchor element to both submit a form and open a new window:

```
<script>

   function submitMyForm()
   {
      // Validate form fields here
      // ...

      // If form is valid, submit it
      myForm.submit(); 
   }

</script>

<a href="javascript:submitMyForm();" target="_blank">Submit Form</a>
```

Comment: But then if the form is submitted but the fields are not filled right the user is taken to a new window?

Comment: So you call a function that validates and then submits it. See my edit.

Comment: what if I don't want to validate with javascript ( my form is validated using php ) I actually fixed it by putting `window.open()` on the landing page where a successful form submit is handled. One problem remains though... `window.open()` is seen as a popup and blocked by modern browsers.

Comment: You can validate with PHP **from** your Javascript using AJAX. Using jQuery, you'd make an `ajax()` call that sends the form values to a PHP script for validation, in the `success:` callback, you place the form submit portion.

Comment: that is an option, but that doesn't fix the problem I have now. But I'll accept this as solution for my original question.